# Cassandra CQL - update (insert) if not equal to

Tags: if-statement, cassandra, cql

I have a scenario where I need to update (or insert) a record if a (non-key) field is not equal to some string OR the record does not exist. For example, given something like:

`UPDATE mytable SET firstname='John', lastname='Doe' WHERE id='1' IF lastname != 'Doe';`

If the lastname is not currently 'Doe', then update it, or if the record does not exist, update (insert) it. My assumption was that the IF condition would yield true if there was no record, but apparently not. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3):

In Cassandra an `UPDATE` behaves very similar as the `INSERT` statement, as explained in the Apache CQL Documenation:

> "Note that unlike in SQL, `UPDATE` does not check the prior existence of the row by default (except through IF, see below): the row is created if none existed before, and updated otherwise. Furthermore, there are no means to know whether a creation or update occurred." - [CQL Documentation - Update](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#update)

I did a simple test and it did work:

```
cqlsh:test_keyspace> select * from conditional_updating ;

id | firstname | lastname
----+-----------+----------

(0 rows)

cqlsh:test_keyspace> update conditional_updating 
                       set firstname = 'John', 
                           lastname = 'Doe' 
                       WHERE id = 1 IF lastname != 'Doe';

 [applied]
-----------
  True

cqlsh:test_keyspace> select * from conditional_updating ;

 id | firstname | lastname
----+-----------+----------
  1 |      John |      Doe

(1 rows)

cqlsh:test_keyspace> update conditional_updating 
                       set lastname = 'New' 
                       WHERE id = 1 IF lastname != 'Doe';

 [applied] | lastname
-----------+----------
     False |      Doe
```

Note that using the `IF` condition isn't free Under the hood it triggers a lightweight transaction (LWT) (also known as CAS for Compara and SET). Such queries require a read and a write and they also need to reach consensus among all replicas, which makes it a bit onerous.

> "But, please note that using IF conditions will incur a non-negligible performance cost (internally, Paxos will be used) so this should be used sparingly." - [CQL Documentation - Update](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#update)

If you are interested in knowing why Lightweight transactions are considered an **anti-pattern** in Cassandra I encourage you to have a look here: **[Lightweight Transactions In Cassandra](https://blog.pythian.com/lightweight-transactions-cassandra/)**

Comment: I'm at a loss as to why my UPDATE is not inserting a record when it does not exist. I've tried the same as above and [applied] is always false.

Comment: What version of cassandra are you running? My test was on 3.11.2, though this should not make a difference. I can do a test with your version if you like.

Comment: I'm using version 2.2.

Comment: I ran the same query against 3.0.x and it works as you stated, but does not work with 2.2. It would be good if you can confirm as well. The strange thing is that I'm sure it did work at some point against 2.2

Comment: I will do a quick test once I have a chance to confirm your findings about 2.2

Comment: Cassandra Conditional Update combined with IF EXISTS
Unfortunately, it's not possible in Cassandra. You have to separate the insert and update statement.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8335

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this documentation as this is what you need and in Cassandra **UPDAtE** Query act as an insert if not exists.
[update with condition](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/update_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_g4h_qzq_xj__synopsis_unique_35)

**Example:**

```
UPDATE keyspace_name.table_name
USING option AND option
SET assignment, assignment, ...
WHERE row_specification 
IF column_name = literal AND column_name = literal . . . 
IF EXISTS
```

Comment: I have already referred to that doc and it does not explain the scenario I've described. If I run the statement I originally posted `UPDATE mytable SET firstname='John', lastname='Doe' WHERE id='1' IF lastname != 'Doe';` , the record is NOT created if record with id='1' does not exist.

Comment: you are missing IF EXISTS check which will yield true or false for your condition

Comment: I don't believe you can use both IF <condition> with IF EXISTS.

Comment: I'm saying very same you stated above you can use but you are not using that.

Comment: I don't think we're on the same page. What I'm trying to achieve is to have a *single* statement which can achieve either 1) conditional IF update of record OR 2) insert if not exists. Ideally I don't want to split this into 2 statements.

Comment: You can only use one of them.  Conditionally update columns using IF or IF EXISTS.